# io.Copy is a lot slower than calling the mv command

Tags: windows, go

It seems io.Copy is slow for me:

```
   _,err = io.Copy(destf,srcf)
```

io.Copy takes longer, about 2 minutes to copy a 1GB file to a network share. Noticed that mv.exe finishes the job in ~25 seconds max - so I've started to evoke mv for my jobs.

```
    output, err := exec.Command("mv", src, dest_folder).CombinedOutput()
```

This slowness is consistently reproducible on my end, Any tips on how to speeden will be much appreciated!

**Update:**

Thanks for the suggestion to use `io.CopyBuffer()`, however `mv.exe` still emerges as the sole victor, by a respectable margin.

Details:

```
PS C:\temp> .\move_files.exe .\testfile.data "\\somehost\somefolder\bleh13.txt"
2018/07/14 19:04:54 Created C:\Temp\2\deleteME__913153343, copy of .\testfile.data, Size: 1073745920 bytes
2018/07/14 19:05:55 Transfer with io.Copy() took us 60.836702 seconds
2018/07/14 19:06:47 Transfer with io.CopyBuffer() took us 50.729625 seconds
2018/07/14 19:06:59 Transfer with mv command took us 11.470456 seconds
PS C:\temp>
```

You're welcome to try this yourself : https://play.golang.org/p/2_lR83A4BXe

Comment: Quite possibly `mv.exe` uses some native NT syscall—supposedly aware of the SMB{2|3} protocol—to streamline upload. I'd use [`procmon`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace what Win32 API call it uses for copying the file, and then consider creating a simple wrapper for in in your Go program.

Comment: I think it's [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) or `CopyFileEx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing my comment suggesting to try the [`CopyFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile) Win32 API function, here's a working program which wraps it:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

var (
    kernel32     = syscall.MustLoadDLL("kernel32.dll")
    copyFileProc = kernel32.MustFindProc("CopyFileW")
)

func CopyFile(src, dst string, overwrite bool) error {
    srcW := syscall.StringToUTF16(src)
    dstW := syscall.StringToUTF16(dst)

    var failIfExists uintptr
    if overwrite {
        failIfExists = 0
    } else {
        failIfExists = 1
    }

    rc, _, err := copyFileProc.Call(
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&srcW[0])),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&dstW[0])),
        failIfExists)
    if rc == 0 {
        return &os.PathError{
            Op:   "CopyFile",
            Path: src,
            Err:  err,
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(0)

    if len(os.Args) != 3 {
        log.Fatalf("Wrong # args.\nUsage: %s SOURCE DEST\n", os.Args[0])
    }

    err := CopyFile(os.Args[1], os.Args[2], false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("error copying file: ", err)
    }
}
```

Please try it and see whether it improves over `io.Copy*`.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, possibly a better fit than my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC, thanks! My line of reasoning actually started with thinking about SMB2+ supporting server-side file copying—with relatively contemporary versions of Windows (Win8+)  making _transparent_ use of it (i.e. it works for Windows Explorer shell operations). So these API calls theoretically may have some specialized logic for the case when one side is an SMB endpoint, too.

Comment: Wow! this is terrific! completes in about 12 seconds! Bravo!

Answer (score 8):

You compare copy and move which are different things. Moving a file doesn't assume writing a copy of all data into the new physical memory destination, just rewriting some headers/descriptors in the file system.  So for proper comparison benchmark

- [os.Rename(oldpath, newpath string)](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Rename) vs mv.exe
- `io.Copy` vs cp.exe

Comment: mv is equivalent to cp + rm, when done across different disk. On same partition mv is almost instant. In OP exemple the mv took 26 seconds, so it’s unlikely to be on same partition.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try [`io.CopyBuffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#CopyBuffer): `io.Copy` uses a [buffer of 32*1024 bytes](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/00ebfcde7f3b6e63447e2a3962975e0a8c3729dd/src/io/io.go#L391).

Check if a bigger or smaller buffer size makes a difference.

Comment: Pls see update in question, `io.CopyBuffer()` is a little better, but native `mv` performs the best.